# how to read response when clicked on button of bootstrap popup?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing MVC application. I am using bootstrp for CSS.

I want to use alert/dialog for confirmation on the delete the record. 
It should ask for OK/Cancel and according to the button click next process will be carried out...

I have get the below code form some forum, it works fine but didn't get any event if I clicked on OK or cancel button

How to read these click events from below code ?

```
$('#Deactivate').click(function () {


    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
        $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h6 id="dataConfirmLabel">Deactivation Confirmation</h6></div><div class="modal-body"><h3>Are you sure to deactive @Model.Name ?</h3> </div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button><a class="btn btn-primary" id="dataConfirmOK">OK</a></div></div>');
    } 
    $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
    $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('href', href);
    $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});


    $('#dataConfirmOK').on('click', function(e) 
    {
        alert('@Model.Id');

       var url2 = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("DeactivateParty", "Party", new { @id = "PoNo"}))";
        alert(url2);
        url2 = url2.replace("PoNo", '@Model.Id');

        $.post(url2, function (data) {
            if(data == true)
            {
                var url = $("#RedirectTo").val();
                location.href = url ;

            }
    });

    return false;




});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify an event handler for your Ok button:

```
$('#dataConfirmOK').on('click', function(e) {
    // Call your delete action here
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jan, I have updated my question. It works perfectly when I dont put any code inside the **dataConfirmOK** , but I put any code on OK button then it dont work... Please check my updated question...

Comment: Code inside the button event dont work... I have put  `alert('@Model.Id');` to check whether cursor comes into that funtion or not, but it wont come...whether I have written any wrong code ?

Comment: issue solved, It was syntax error, Thanks for your support Jan

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a syntax error closing off the post method:

```
$.post(url2, function (data) {
    if(data == true)
    {
        var url = $("#RedirectTo").val();
        location.href = url;
    }
```

Should be...

```
$.post(url2, function (data) {
    if(data == true)
    {
        var url = $("#RedirectTo").val();
        location.href = url ;
    }
})
```

n.b If you dump your posted code into the console window of your favorite browser, you'll see the error.

Comment: @user1650894 It might be worth marking an answer in case people attempt to provide more.